# Get the first product id in a magento system via soap api (2)?

Tags: soap, magento-1.7

Question:  Is there a way (api call) to get the first product id in a magento install via the soap api.

I'm attempting to download all the products from a magento system and insert them into a  different database  (I do the conversion myself so that's not a bother)  What is hard to understand though is how do I get a list of the product id's without getting all of them, if all I know is that the site is up.

Here's the info I have.
 
soap end point
soap username
soap apikey (aka password)

Here's what I don't know.
the id of any of the products
the date any of the products were created on or last edited.

For my initial load, I have to do a where product id in, because I expect 20 to 40k product lists won't come back in one soap call.
So I call 
where id in (1 -> 100)  Nope
where id in (101-> 200)  Nope..

Now as you can imagine that code smells something fierce. It works, but I have to think there is a better way..

To expand my question:  Is there a better way?

I can post the XML that I'm sending if that helps.  The language I'm using to create the soap(xml) is vim, so I don't have code I can paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento8/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('soap username', 'soap apikey');
$filters=array('entity_id'=>array(array('lt'=>'1','gt'=>'100')));//get fist 100 result
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list',array($filters));
var_dump($result);
```

for more attributes check this
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento